# What is the second line of "La prueba de amor" by Cumbia Vallenata

Tags: letras-de-canciones

I've been listening to "La prueba de amor" by Cumbia Vallenata and cannot figure out the second line of the song. The lyrics are also nowhere online.

The first line is definitely:

```
Dame la prueba de amor
```

However, the second line is something like

```
No quiero sólo ...
```

I can't figure it out. Would you be able to take a listen and tell me what the second line is? Thank you so much.

["Pa prueba de amor" by Cumbia Vallenata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpnnG8ejFB0)

Comment: Take a look at this link:https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS842US842&ei=i0dMXZfQOMHGsQWDpKaYAQ&q=prueba+de+amor+letra&oq=Prueba+de+amor+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0i71l3.10570.10570..12217...0.0..0.0.0.......2....1..gws-wiz.m9zMwKrZAB0

Comment: Why? That does not appear to be the same song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola Leo Galleguillos,

"No quiero solo besitos".